# How to map the objects that having the dynamic keys in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
const arr = [
  {
    2671161009: {
      activityType: 'RUNNING',
      averageHeartRateInBeatsPerMinute: 134,
      comments: '',
      durationInSeconds: 3884,
      startTimeInSeconds: 1525368621,
      startTimeOffsetInSeconds: -14400,
      summaryId: '2671161009',
    },
    2671161249: {
      activityType: 'OTHER',
      averageHeartRateInBeatsPerMinute: 111,
      comments: '',
      durationInSeconds: 103,
      startTimeInSeconds: 1525372533,
      startTimeOffsetInSeconds: -14400,
      summaryId: '2671161249',
    },
  },
];
```

That index keys that having the is generate dynamically. How can we map this array data in React? Could you please give me the suggestion.

Comment: exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Can't you simply use `Array.map` to loop over the array?

Comment: I want to map this array and render into the table

Comment: Can you post the expected output ?

Comment: No i can't be able to use the map method, Because that key indexes is generating dynamically

Comment: What do you mean by `index keys`?, I don't see a key name index.

Comment: @Manikanta You are quite unclear in this post: as Mritunjay suggested: can't you just write down what do you expect as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const yourData = [{
    "2671161009": {
        "activityType": "RUNNING",
        "averageHeartRateInBeatsPerMinute": 134,
        "comments": "",
        "durationInSeconds": 3884,
        "startTimeInSeconds": 1525368621,
        "startTimeOffsetInSeconds": -14400,
        "summaryId": "2671161009",
    },
    "2671161249": {
        "activityType": "OTHER",
        "averageHeartRateInBeatsPerMinute": 111,
        "comments": "",
        "durationInSeconds": 103,
        "startTimeInSeconds": 1525372533,
        "startTimeOffsetInSeconds": -14400,
        "summaryId": "2671161249",
    },
}];

const activityData = yourData[0];// You have the entire object as the first element in an array. I don't know why;

const activityIds = Object.keys(activityData);
const activities = activityIds.map(activityID => ({
    id: activityID,
    ...activityData[activityID]
}));
```

You can now map this `activities` array as you wish.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to access all key-value pairs of the object:

```
<div>
  {arr.map(obj =>
    Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => (
      <tr key={key}>
        <td>Key: {key}</td>
        <td>Activity Type: {value.activityType}</td>
        <td>DurationInSeconds: {value.durationInSeconds}</td>
      </tr>
    )))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey how about a one liner code

```
Object.entries(b[0]).map((item , index)=>
 <tr key={index}>
        <td>Activity Type: {item[1].activityType}</td>
        <td>DurationInSeconds: {item[1].durationInSeconds}</td>
  </tr>
)
```

in  `Object.entries(b[0])` you will get your entries in an array then loop that array as your wish